# How can a non-administrator view the filters on a defined report type?

Tags: reporting, report-builder

Background:  I'm working at $VERY-LARGE-COMPANY.  I am not a Salesforce Admin, and getting the admins to make any changes requires a lot of lead time and a strong business justification.

I am having trouble creating a report to find certain records - cases where $related-object-1.$field1 has value $value1.  When my report runs it is missing a lot of cases I know exist and are visible to me, and I notice that all the returned case records have a similar pattern in case.$field2.  I suspect that the custom report type which combines cases and $relasted-object-1 was created with a filter on case.$field2.

How can I find out for sure, without talking to a (very busy and overworked) administrator?

Comment: custom report types don't define filters, at best they define whether children objects may or must exist, they also define which fields are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a dummy `$related-object-1` with some value in `$field1` and a different value in `$field2`, then run the report?

Comment: I don't have to create a dummy to test my search -- I have a slew of examples that are linked from a manually maintained spreadsheet, where $field1 has value $value1 and $field2 has something that doesn't match the cases on the report.  I'm trying to replace the spreadsheet. :-)  I'll edit my question to make that more clear.